# How get aria-rowindex value in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image]

how get aria-rowindex value for event

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Please add more information to your question, add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or describe more clearly what exactly you are doing.

I will try to answer your question the way I understand it:

You probably attach your EventListener with vue's `@click` directive? In this case you can pass the original `event` to your handler via the special `$event` variable, e.g. `<tr aria-rowindex="10" role="row" @click="handler($event)">..</tr>`.

In case you attach the EventListener with vanilla JavaScript (`element.addEventListener('click', callback)`) your callback get the Event passed as the first parameter.

In both cases you can access the element via `event.target`, this represents the actual HTMLElement. The aria-rowindex is a regular attribute on the HTMLElement which you can access with `element.getAttribute('aria-rowindex')`.

#### Example

```
    <tr aria-rowindex="10" role="row" @click="handler($event)">..</tr>
    
    handler(event) {
      const rowIndex = event.target.getAttribute('aria-rowindex');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

{{data.item.id}}
          
          
            **{{data.item.name}}**
          
          
            {{data.item.status}}
          
         
                Freischalten</b-button>
            </template>
          
                Verwerfen</b-button>
          </template> -->
      
        
          Edit
          Delete
          Accept
          Reject

```
    </b-table>
    <nav>
      <b-pagination size="sm" :total-rows="getRowCountunlog(unlogname)" :per-page="perPage" v-model="currentPage" prev-text="Prev" next-text="Next" hide-goto-end-buttons/>
    </nav>
  </b-tab>
  </b-tabs>
```

how make search